# How can I identify sentences within a text?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, sentence

I have text that looks like this:-

```
"I am an engineer. I am skilled in ASP.NET. I also know Node.js.But I don't have much experience. "
```

Here, "ASP.NET" and "Node.js" are to be treated as words. Also, there is no space before "But I...", but it should be treated as a separate sentence.

The expected output is:

```
["I am an engineer"," I am skilled in ASP.NET","I also know Node.js","But I don't have much experience"]
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Use NLTK or any other NLP package to break arbitrary paragraphs into sentences. Regex is not the best tool for this. Unless you have some very specific input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current input you may use the following approach with `re.split()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = "I am an engineer. I am skilled in ASP.NET. I also know Node.js.But I don't have much experience. "
result = re.split(r'\.(?=\s?[A-Z][^.]*? )', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['I am an engineer', ' I am skilled in ASP.NET', ' I also know Node.js', "But I don't have much experience. "]
```

---

`(?=\s?[A-Z][^.]*? )` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that sentence delimiter `.` is followed by word from next sentence